# Updated phone now texts are mixed

Tags: iphone, ios

My father updated his iPhone software to iOS 6. Now his wife is recieving his text messages. We tried going to settings and turning off iMessage but that just stopped his phone from getting some of the messages.

How can I fix this problem.  Note: they share the same Apple ID.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more details, I cannot know this for certain, but it seems likely that your father's wife is receiving iMessages sent to him, but not SMS text messages. This is the designed behavior – iMessages are delivered to an Apple ID, and if they share an Apple ID, iMessages will go to both of them. The solution is for them to *not* share an Apple ID.

That said, one can set up a different Apple ID for Messages but keep the same Apple ID for the App store, iTunes, etc. This would alloow them to share purchases, but keep their messages separate from each other.

You can also go into Settings > Messages > Send & Receive and un-check mark the email address that is associated with both of their phones (and Apple IDs). There is a good chance that will also fix your problem.

Answer (score 0):

To stop messages going to multiple phones:
go to settings, then messages, then send & receive...
from there deselect the numbers you don't want to receive your texts.

Answer (score 0):

I updated my iPhone to 6.1.3 and it set it automatically...so when I texted my kids they said it showed as being from my wife's iPhone.

To turn off...go to Settings > Messages and you want to turn OFF the top item, "iMessage"

This fixed it for us!

Comment: Might be important to add that this turns off iMessages completely which depending on your needs might not be exactly what you want.